# How does snowflake route notifications to pipes knowing they share the same SQS queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-sqs, snowpipe

When I run

```
SHOW PIPES
```

I can see that all the snowpipes have the same notification_channel value. I'm using SQS to send event notifications to snowpipes, with filters on the file path.

But, even if all the snowpipes have the same notification_channel as I've mentionned above (which is basically the SQS quee ARN) and are using the same stage, every SNOWPIPE loads only the relevant files. I wonder how each SNOWPIPE ignore the notifications which are not addressed to it?

I'm asking because I'm working on moving SNOWPIPES from one schema to another (along with the tables), so wanted to understand if I create a SNOWPIPE and give the same value for notification channel, will it receive the right notifications?

Comment: Your pipe is based on a COPY INTO command, and the files based on the COPY INTO are the ones loaded.

Comment: So all the pipes receive the same notification, and only those which will find files actually load data?